# Parse.com PFQuery order by time (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to get all the objects depeding on how recently they were created but its always returning from the start and i want latest first, here is my code

```
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notes")
query.orderByDescending("CreatedAt")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects,error) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
      for object in objects {
         self.array.addObject(object)
      }
   }
}
```

I tried ascending order but still returns same objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is just that `"createdAt"` field starts with a lowercase 'C', not an uppercase, so you should try:

```
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
```

Comment: that worked, sometimes small mistakes takes all the time

Comment: Yes, I can relate to that :)