# UICollectionView - Sort order: Date

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am creating this app, and I am using `NSDate` extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    var timeAgo: String {
        let minute = 60
        let hour = 60 * minute
        let day = 24 * hour
        let secondsAgo = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self))
        if secondsAgo < 0            { return  "later"                           }
        if secondsAgo == 0           { return "now"                              }
        if secondsAgo == 1           { return "1 second ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < minute       { return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"        }
        if secondsAgo < (2 * minute) { return "1 minute ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < hour         { return "\(secondsAgo/minute) minutes ago" }
        if secondsAgo < 2 * hour     { return "1 hour ago"                       }
        if secondsAgo < day          { return "\(secondsAgo / hour) hours ago"   }
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

I am loading the date form Parse.com, and to load this on the label on the `UICollectionView`, I am using this:

```
cell.uploadedTimeLabel.text = post.CreatedAt.timeAgo
```

So when I now see it on runtime, it says "30 seconds ago", "2 minutes ago".

But how can I sort this, so the newest comes to the top?

Comment: The sort has to be done in the data source, like sort by CreatedAt of your (array of) objects posts.

Comment: @Larme - How should i do that?

Comment: You are using parse.com. I guess that somewhere you're making a query to get PFObjects. You can add a sort in your request.

Comment: @Larme - Do you mean this: http://pastebin.com/ETuiCKrS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518734/parse-com-pfquery-order-by-time-swift

Comment: @Larme - I added the "query.orderByDescending("createdAt")" after query classname line, but it does not order by date.. "createdAt" is the column form parse.com