# How do I use the data within my query within a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am making a basic iOS application, within that application I have a table-view-controller. I need this controller to populate the cells based on information in my Parse.com database.

Here is the information I specifically need:

- candidateName (which is a string)
- candidateImage (which is an image file)

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      // Retrieves the name from DB
      let nameQuery = PFQuery(className: "Candidate")

      // Network request
      nameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
          (result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          if error == nil && result != nil {

              // The find succeeded.
              println(result?.count)
          } else {

              // Log details of the failure
              println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I am getting the objects back as expected, but how do I get specifically just the name and the image? Do I do two separate queries for each piece of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of great tutorials out there for iOS Swift + Parse. [Dive into a tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581) and you'll have an easy time learning how to get the job done.

In response to your latter questions, you will only need one query as long as you have associated the name and image to the Candidate class.

Good luck and have fun with it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to apologize in advance, I'm going to write the answers in objective-C, as I have yet to learn swift! :-) So basically in your class create an `NSArray`. Let's suppose you name it data. In your `viewDidLoad`, just use:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Candidate"];
data = [query findObjects];
```

In your `numberOfRowsInSection`, just put `return [query countObjects];`

In `cellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you can get the data of an object by doing `((PFObject *)(data[indexPath.row]))[@"attr"]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate it, I get the concept slightly better, would be nice if it were in swift though!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't write it in swift. This link should be a good reference though! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518734/parse-com-pfquery-order-by-time-swift